# What is the purpose of the 'tracking.history' MongoDB database?

Tags: xdb, aggregation

Sitecore XP version `8.0`, `8.1` and `8.2` comes with following MongoDB databases:

- `analytics`
- `tracking.live`
- `tracking.history`
- `tracking.contact`

What is the purpose of the `tracking.history` database in MongoDB?

Answer (score 5):

### Tracking History

The `tracking.history` database is used by one entity only:

- *History Processing Pool* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.ProcessingPools.config` file).

#### History Processing Pool

It works with the `ProcessingPool` collection that is defined in the `tracking.history` database. During aggregation of a history data (rebuild of the `reporting` SQL database aka RDB) this pool is populated with the work items.

The *History Processing Pool* is referenced by two entities:

- *History Task Manager* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.ProcessingPools.config` file)
- *History Interaction Aggregation Context* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.config` file)

#### History Task Manager

It manages all tasks related to aggregation of history data, and is used by various agents that are responsible for history data aggregation (rebuild of the `reporting` database).

#### History Interaction Aggregation context

It is referenced by the *Interaction Work Dispatcher* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config` file), where the dispatcher is used by the *Aggregation Cleanup* and *Aggregation Recovery* agents (both defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config` file).

Additionally, both the *History Interaction Aggregation Context* and *History Task Manager* are used by the *History Worker* (defined in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.Services.config` file). The worker runs by the *Processing / Aggregation* role. It gets work items from the history processing pool using the *History Task Manager*. Each work item is processed by calling the `analytics.aggregation/interactions` pipeline.